# How to list available repo versions using Docker

Tags: docker, version

Is there a way to let Docker list all the available image versions that can be downloaded?

Let's say I want to get the latest version of Apache, then I could type this:

```
docker pull httpd:latest
```

Now, if I am interested in a particular version, I could type this:

```
docker pull httpd:2.4.34
```

In order to be able to do that though, I need to know that there is a version `2.4.34` available. Now, is there a way to list available versions? I am looking for something similar to this:

```
docker list httpd versions
```

and I would like to have a response similar to this:

```
2.4.34
2.4.32
2.4.29
2.2.34
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API endpoint for this action which is explained here:

```
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags
```

The endpoint itself is the following:

```
/v1/repositories/(namespace)/(repository)/tags
```

So you can run the following command in order to access it:

```
curl -u <username>:<password> https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/<username>/<image_name>/tags
```

Comment: It's curious that this API is not implemented in the Docker CLI because it's very useful. To be clear, this answer only applies to DockerHub (docker.io) and, for other registries e.g. Google Container Registry, there is a command to enumerate both the registries images (`gcloud container images list`) and tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if docker supports this, but `podman` has `--list-tags`:

```
podman search nginx --list-tags
```

which shows (truncated):

```
NAME                     TAG
docker.io/library/nginx  1
docker.io/library/nginx  1-alpine
docker.io/library/nginx  1-alpine-perl
docker.io/library/nginx  1-perl
docker.io/library/nginx  1.10
...
docker.io/library/nginx  1.11.12
docker.io/library/nginx  1.11.12-alpine
docker.io/library/nginx  1.11.13
```

The `--limit` paramater can come handy with `--list-tags` when there are a lot of results. `podman search --list-tags --limit 1000 docker.io/library/mariadb` displays 365 results...

Answer (score 0):

Use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo)

```
brew install skopeo
skopeo list-tags docker://docker.io/redis
skopeo list-tags docker://container-registry.oracle.com/database/free
```

This will return a JSON object showing all of the available image versions

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the [OCI Tag Listing API](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/v1.1.0/spec.md#listing-tags). A shell script to call that on Docker Hub looks like:

```bash
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
             -u "${username}:${password}" \
        | jq -r '.token')
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/tags/list" | jq .
```

However, I'd recommend using one of the various tools designed for this that will help with authentication (or anonymous access) and pagination (when the number of tags exceeds the registry limit). Here are a few tools that I'm ware of:

Crane from Google:

```bash
$ crane ls busybox
1
1-glibc
1-musl
1-ubuntu
1-uclibc
1.21-ubuntu
1.21.0-ubuntu
1.23
1.23.2
1.24
1.24-glibc
1.24-musl
1.24-uclibc
...
```

ORAS from Microsoft:

```bash
$ oras repo tags docker.io/library/busybox
1
1-glibc
1-musl
1-ubuntu
1-uclibc
1.21-ubuntu
1.21.0-ubuntu
1.23
1.23.2
1.24
1.24-glibc
1.24-musl
1.24-uclibc
...
```

Skopeo from RedHat:

```bash
$ skopeo list-tags docker://docker.io/library/busybox
{
    "Repository": "docker.io/library/busybox",
    "Tags": [
        "1",
        "1-glibc",
        "1-musl",
        "1-ubuntu",
        "1-uclibc",
        "1.21-ubuntu",
        "1.21.0-ubuntu",
        "1.23",
        "1.23.2",
        "1.24",
        "1.24-glibc",
        "1.24-musl",
        "1.24-uclibc",
...
```

regctl from myself:

```bash
$ regctl tag ls busybox
1
1-glibc
1-musl
1-ubuntu
1-uclibc
1.21-ubuntu
1.21.0-ubuntu
1.23
1.23.2
1.24
1.24-glibc
1.24-musl
1.24-uclibc
...
```